# "Target filesystem doesn't have sbin/init" after cloning boot disk with dd

Tags: dd

I cloned a boot disk (bootloader, `/` and `swap` partitions) with dd to the same size disk (bad sectors started to appear). Got 1 reading error in the middle of the disk. After I swapped the disks I received "Target filesystem doesn't have sbin/init" error. At first I thought that the problem is `/etc/fstab` points to the wrong UUID to boot off. It turns out new disk has the same UUID, but I changed it to `/dev/sda` just to be shure and it is indeed `/dev/sda` (I disconnected all other disks). The problem persists.
How could it be that from 2 identical disks one is okay and the other not?
**Edit:**
I just mounted the new disk (it's LVM except /boot - does this matter?) and I can't read anything - "Input/output error". So why I receive "Target filesystem doesn't have sbin/init" now solved. I did try this before, I swear. But I did `ls` on it, saw my root directory and decided that it's okay.

Comment: Did you use `dd conv=noerror,sync`?

Comment: @mark4o just `conv=noerror`. sync? "pad every input block with NULs  to  ibs-size" - what's this for?

Comment: Without `noerror` it will stop copying when it sees an error.  With `noerror` but not `sync` it will skip over the input block that is in error but then all of the blocks after that will be written to the wrong place (one block earlier).  `conv=noerror,sync` will write a block of zeros for every error block to keep input & output synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that dd doesn't play well when there are errors on the disk.  Maybe try using dd_rescue to image bootloader, / and swap to the new disk.  Otherwise you might try imaging the entire disk.

dd_rescue works the exact same way as dd but can handle errors.

Comment: Yes, that's probably because of the reading errors. I'll try dd_rescue